# Azure VM creation automation using Terraform and Jenkins?

Tags: azure, jenkins, terraform

I have the Terraform script/template to provision a VM in Azure,it accepts the input and provision the VM along with the required resources.

I have created the Azure Storage Account and uploaded the script into the blob container.

We are using Jenkins as our CI/CD tool.

Now, I want to build the pipeline or automation using Jenkins which would take the necessary input and run Terraform script to provision the VM.

How do I build the Jenkins pipeline so that I can run the pipeline / automation multiple times and provision the individual VMs?

Any sample Jenkins pipeline would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your sole purpose is to run the terraform through jenkins then there are many pipeline scripts available , I have pasted one below the link, which will help to build a jenkins pipeline and has guided documentation as well.

https://github.com/manheim/terraform-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated architecture reference and sample available on the Azure documentation on [Immutable Infrastructure CI/CD using Jenkins and Terraform on Azure Virtual Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/immutable-infrastructure-cicd-using-jenkins-and-terraform-on-azure-virtual-architecture-overview)

And here is the [`template`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/jenkins-cicd-vmss/) as well

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name <resource-group-name> -Location <resource-group-location> #use this command when you need to create a new resource group for your deployment
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/application-workloads/jenkins/jenkins-cicd-vmss/azuredeploy.json
```